Lock not released on rollback / deadlock unresolvable
I have a very weird issue related to transaction management that I simply do not understand. I am Oracle developer, but we switched to PostgreSQL for the project we are working on, and with obvious differences between two databases I might be missing something that is specific to PostgreSQL.
We have two sessions inserting same data in the table, but in a different order. Obviously, this leads to a deadlock error. We expect that the data will be rolled back on error, so we are using loop to run the same code again in case of a deadlock. Since data is rolled back, we expect that other session successfully inserted and committed the data, and session that got error should proceed without errors on next loop.
If we use exception handlers anywhere in the code (except at the top level) deadlock is raised again, and this repeats on each loop. If we remove exception handlers, the above approach works as expected - deadlock is raised only once, and on the next loop there are no errors.
PostgreSQL version we are using is 16.
I am providing a simplified example, but it shows exactly what the problem is.
Table definition:
CREATE TABLE public.dummy (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    ext_id text NOT NULL,
    description text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT dummy_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT dummy_uk UNIQUE (ext_id)
);

We run the following code in the first session, which generates id for the first object, waits 5 seconds and tries to generate id for the second object:
do $$
declare
  l_max_retries integer := 2;
  l_retry_count integer := 0;
  l_sleep_timer numeric := 0.1;
  l_id1 int8;
  l_id2 int8;
begin
  loop
    begin
      raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, before first insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
      begin
        insert into public.dummy (ext_id, description)
        values ('object1', 'first session')
        on conflict (ext_id) do nothing
        returning id into l_id1;
        raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, id1: %, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_id1, l_retry_count;
      exception -- if exception block is removed, everything will work fine after the first deadlock
        when others then
          raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, exception on first insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
          raise;
      end;
      raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, after first insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;

      perform pg_sleep(5);

      raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, before second insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
      begin
        insert into public.dummy (ext_id, description)
        values ('object2', 'first session')
        on conflict (ext_id) do nothing
        returning id into l_id2;
        raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, id2: %, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_id2, l_retry_count;
      exception -- if exception block is removed, everything will work fine after the first deadlock
        when others then
          raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, exception on second insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
          raise;
      end;
      raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, after second insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;

      perform pg_sleep(5);
      exit;
    exception
      when deadlock_detected then
        l_retry_count := l_retry_count + 1;
        raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, deadlock #%', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
        perform pg_sleep(l_sleep_timer);
        if l_retry_count = l_max_retries + 1 then
          raise 'Too many retries while trying to resolve deadlock error.';
        end if;
    end;
  end loop;
end$$;

We run the following code in the second session - same thing, only with reverse order of inserts. It tries to insert object 2, and afterwards object 1, which leads to a deadlock error.
do $$
declare
  l_max_retries integer := 2;
  l_retry_count integer := 0;
  l_sleep_timer numeric := 0.1;
  l_id1 int8;
  l_id2 int8;
begin
  loop
    begin
      raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, before first insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
      begin
        insert into public.dummy (ext_id, description)
        values ('object2', 'second session')
        on conflict (ext_id) do nothing
        returning id into l_id2;
        raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, id2: %, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_id2, l_retry_count;
      exception -- if exception block is removed, everything will work fine after the first deadlock
        when others then
          raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, exception on first insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
          raise;
      end;
      raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, after first insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;

      perform pg_sleep(5);

      raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, before second insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
      begin
        insert into public.dummy (ext_id, description)
        values ('object1', 'second session')
        on conflict (ext_id) do nothing
        returning id into l_id1;
        raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, id1: %, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_id1, l_retry_count;
      exception -- if exception block is removed, everything will work fine after the first deadlock
        when others then
          raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, exception on second insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
          raise;
      end;
      raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, after second insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;

      perform pg_sleep(5);
      exit;
    exception
      when deadlock_detected then
        l_retry_count := l_retry_count + 1;
        raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, deadlock #%', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
        perform pg_sleep(l_sleep_timer);
        if l_retry_count = l_max_retries + 1 then
          raise 'Too many retries while trying to resolve deadlock error.';
        end if;
    end;
  end loop;
end$$;

Output from the first session:
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:13.937736+01, before first insert, retry: 0
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:13.938241+01, id1: 1, retry: 0
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:13.938317+01, after first insert, retry: 0
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:18.963503+01, before second insert, retry: 0
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:35.326252+01, id2: 3, retry: 0
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:35.326348+01, after second insert, retry: 0

Output from the second session:
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:16.96078+01, before first insert, retry: 0
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:16.961126+01, id2: 2, retry: 0
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:16.961193+01, after first insert, retry: 0
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:21.983919+01, before second insert, retry: 0
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:22.984332+01, exception on second insert, retry: 0
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:22.984479+01, deadlock #1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:23.086167+01, before first insert, retry: 1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:23.086323+01, id2: 5, retry: 1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:23.086347+01, after first insert, retry: 1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:28.105151+01, before second insert, retry: 1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:29.10542+01, exception on second insert, retry: 1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:29.105499+01, deadlock #2
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:29.207101+01, before first insert, retry: 2
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:29.207235+01, id2: 7, retry: 2
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:29.207258+01, after first insert, retry: 2
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:34.223838+01, before second insert, retry: 2
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:35.224082+01, exception on second insert, retry: 2
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:12:35.224169+01, deadlock #3

With exception handlers deadlock error will lead to the data being rolled back (we can clearly see that from the log because on each loop new id is generated), but the lock on the first object from the second session will not be released. How is this possible? Data is rolled back, lock surely cannot be there? Please note: in this example fix would obviously be to change the order of inserts, but that's not what I'm looking for. Real code is way more complicated and it would be very hard to do this.
Having:
begin
  [some code]
exception
  when others then
    raise;
end;

in my opinion should be exactly the same as:
[some code]

If exception handlers are removed, as in the following example, lock is properly released and everything works as expected. I am aware that using begin ... exception ... end; basically adds savepoints and rolls back to these savepoints in case of errors, but since I am re-raising the error this surely should not affect anything, and data should be rolled back and locks released, right?
First session:
do $$
declare
  l_max_retries integer := 2;
  l_retry_count integer := 0;
  l_sleep_timer numeric := 0.1;
  l_id1 int8;
  l_id2 int8;
begin
  loop
    begin
      raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, before first insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
      insert into public.dummy (ext_id, description)
      values ('object1', 'first session')
      on conflict (ext_id) do nothing
      returning id into l_id1;
      raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, after first insert, id1: %, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_id1, l_retry_count;

      perform pg_sleep(5);

      raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, before second insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
      insert into public.dummy (ext_id, description)
      values ('object2', 'first session')
      on conflict (ext_id) do nothing
      returning id into l_id2;
      raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, after second insert, id2: %, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_id2, l_retry_count;

      perform pg_sleep(5);
      exit;
    exception
      when deadlock_detected then
        l_retry_count := l_retry_count + 1;
        raise notice 'Session 1, timestamp: %, deadlock #%', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
        perform pg_sleep(l_sleep_timer);
        if l_retry_count = l_max_retries + 1 then
          raise 'Too many retries while trying to resolve deadlock error.';
        end if;
    end;
  end loop;
end$$;

Second session:
do $$
declare
  l_max_retries integer := 2;
  l_retry_count integer := 0;
  l_sleep_timer numeric := 0.1;
  l_id1 int8;
  l_id2 int8;
begin
  loop
    begin
      raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, before first insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
      insert into public.dummy (ext_id, description)
      values ('object2', 'second session')
      on conflict (ext_id) do nothing
      returning id into l_id2;
      raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, after first insert, id2: %, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_id2, l_retry_count;

      perform pg_sleep(5);

      raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, before second insert, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
      insert into public.dummy (ext_id, description)
      values ('object1', 'second session')
      on conflict (ext_id) do nothing
      returning id into l_id1;
      raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, after second insert, id1: %, retry: %', clock_timestamp()::text, l_id1, l_retry_count;

      perform pg_sleep(5);
      exit;
    exception
      when deadlock_detected then
        l_retry_count := l_retry_count + 1;
        raise notice 'Session 2, timestamp: %, deadlock #%', clock_timestamp()::text, l_retry_count;
        perform pg_sleep(l_sleep_timer);
        if l_retry_count = l_max_retries + 1 then
          raise 'Too many retries while trying to resolve deadlock error.';
        end if;
    end;
  end loop;
end$$;

Output from the first session:
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:30.303058+01, before first insert, retry: 0
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:30.303921+01, after first insert, id1: 1, retry: 0
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:35.323913+01, before second insert, retry: 0
Session 1, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:38.196913+01, after second insert, id2: 3, retry: 0

Output from the second session:
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:32.176687+01, before first insert, retry: 0
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:32.177043+01, after first inset, id2: 2, retry: 0
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:37.193904+01, before second insert, retry: 0
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:38.196671+01, deadlock #1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:38.29843+01, before first insert, retry: 1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:43.214541+01, after first inset, id2: <NULL>, retry: 1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:48.225552+01, before second insert, retry: 1
Session 2, timestamp: 2024-12-20 21:17:48.225775+01, after second insert, id1: <NULL>, retry: 1

In both cases we have the same lock types:

Real example is way more complicated, but in a nutshell:

We have a source table on which we put a trigger which calls chain of functions that transform the data into our own format.
In the source table we have external ids of the main object, and ids of referenced objects.
Since the source data is coming asynchronously via Kafka, it is possible that referenced objects are still not there, but we still want to generate their ids - we are calling a function that returns an id if it already exists, or inserts an id if not.
Function that generates id is basically this (I am providing some sort of a pseudo code):

...
declare
  l_id int8;
begin
  loop
    select id into l_id from table where ext_id = ...;
    if l_id is null then
      begin
        insert into table ... on conflict (ext_id) do nothing;
      exception
        when unique_violation then
          null;
      end;
    end if;
    if l_id is not null then
      exit;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return l_id;
end;
...


Since we are using dynamic queries, there is no guarantee on the order in which ids are going to be generated, and this probably leads to a deadlock; this is not something we can easily fix (nor do we want to change the approach unless absolutely necessary), so options are to retry the transaction in case of a deadlock (doesn't work due to exception handlers, as seen in the examples in this post), or put the data in the queue and process it later (works, but we are using cron job for this which I don't like, and we don't have time to try with notify/listen approach and a microservice).
Although I briefly explained what the real code is doing, I am not looking for different approaches to what we are doing - I am merely looking for an insight into how usage of exception handlers lead to lock not being released and what am I missing here.


Oracle doesn't behave much different from PostgreSQL when it comes to locks and deadlocks. You can never run into the same deadlock twice, so if deadlocks keep repeating, it must be a new one every time.

It is a new one, but question is why? In the first session we insert object1 and try to insert object2. Object2 is already inserted by the second session (but not committed yet), so insert statement now waits because of the unique key/index. Second session fails with the deadlock and rolls back - with this rollback, insert from the first session should now be unblocked, both object should be successfully inserted and committed. Second session should now retry its two inserts and do not do anything because the data is already there. But it's not working like this with exception handlers.
